# React Native: Building for IOS failed on XCode 9.2 and 9.4 and RN 55.4

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, build

So as the title said, I tried on both Xcode versions and still no luck.
This is the error I'm getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTCxxBridge", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTBridge.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried:

- following these suggestions [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14749)
- cleaning the project between builds
- restarting XCode and the mac itself
- adding modifications to podfile like so:

  ```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
   platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'Absent' do
    # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
    # use_frameworks!

    # Pods for Absent
      pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'
      pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'
      pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/'
      pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
      'RCTGeolocation',
      'RCTNetwork',
      'Core',
      'DevSupport',
      'BatchedBridge',
      'RCTAnimation',
      'RCTText',
      'RCTWebSocket'
      ]

    target 'AbsentTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end

  end

  target 'Absent-tvOS' do
    # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
    # use_frameworks!

    # Pods for Absent-tvOS

    target 'Absent-tvOSTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end

  end

  post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
           target.remove_from_project
       end
   end
  end
  ```
- Tried using `RCTCxxBridge` and `CxxBridge` instead of BatchedBridge because it's supposedly deprecated

But still no luck...
Any pointers would be appreciated here :)

Comment: are you trying to add react native to an existing app?

Comment: @Byron no I'm just trying to create a .ipa file for my pure react native project

Comment: I suggest you remove the yoga and React pods from your pod file and then do the following:
1. Delete your iOS/Pods folder,  
2. delete your src/node_modules folder, 
3. delete your iOS/build folder and then run the commands 

1. npm install and 2. cd ios && pod install and try to build your project again

Comment: @needsleep not a bad idea actually, I'll definitely try that tomorrow n report back here thanks!

Comment: @needsleep it did get me somewhere! turns out my original problem has been solved long ago, i just need to refresh the cached builds and reinstall everything! thanks! now I just have 1 error saying `duplicate symbols for architecture arm64` that I need to solve, but at least I'm not stuck anymore lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comment, apparently it's the previous failed builds cache that's messing up my archiving process. All I had to do was to delete `node_modules`, `ios/builds` and `ios/Pods` then do `npm install`, `react-native link` and `cd ios && pod install` once again and the project was all good.

After that I was getting `duplicate symbols on arm64` error which was simply because both `react-native` and `RCTWebSocket` have some overlapping classes.
So to solve that I just have to delete `libRCTWebSocket.a` from Project's `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` info subcategory on General tab from XCode.

Special thanks to @needsleep for the solution!

Comment: I'm glad you got this working! Unfortunately I find myself repeating the mentioned process more than I would like. Especially when I link a new library. I hope that the react-native team will improve this in the future.

Comment: yes it's pretty annoying indeed when we have to add new libs.. They mentioned updating to RN56 would help with Xcode compatibilities, but RN56 comes with new bugs too that's just more annoying than this one lol thanks again @needsleep!